# Why is the node fs Promises API not recommended?

Tags: node.js, fs

Part of my application involves deleting a large folder and some rows that relate to the files in that folder in a database periodically.
To do this I was thinking of using this code:

```
const { rmdir } = require('fs/promises');

... begin transaction
... remove database rows
await rmdir(dir, { recursive: true });
... end transaction
```

The reason I want to use the Promises API instead of rmdirSync (which stops the entire server) is that I want the server to keep accepting requests while the operating system is busy deleting the folder. I know I could just use the callback api and just end the transaction before the folder is deleted, but that may lead to inconsistencies and also wouldn't catch any potential errors. (the files might still be served by `express.static` while the database rows are already gone)

But I read in this documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_callback_example
That the use of the Promise API is not recommended in favour of the callback API.

So here's my questions:

- Why is it slower to use the Promise API instead of the Callback API?
- How much slower?
- Could I just do this instead:

  ```
  const { unlink } = require('fs');

  ... begin transaction
  ... remove database rows
  await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    unlink('/tmp/hello', (err) => {
       resolve()
    })
  });
  ... end transaction
  ```

Comment: It explains it here: 

"The callback-based versions of the fs module APIs are preferable over the use of the promise APIs when maximal performance (both in terms of execution time and memory allocation are required)."

The other questions you can answer yourself by doing experimentation....

Comment: Well it doesn't explain why that is or how severe it is. But yes I should probably just experiement. Would still be nice if they explained it further though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promises api does exactly the same thing as your included code:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  unlink('/tmp/hello', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }

    resolve()
  })
});
```

The memory and time difference is directly related to the promises. Callback API uses bare c++, but promises require an additional layer of logic.

There is probably no difference until you make a million operations per second.